# Plugin with id 'com.android.model.native' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I am trying to develop a module from my C project with Android Studio.  I am having the problem of

Plugin with id 'com.android.model.native' not found.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Below is the App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.native"

model {
    android {

        compileSdkVersion 27

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = 'com.example.androidthings.nativepio'
            minSdkVersion 27
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        ndk {
            //platformVersion = "21"
            moduleName "libusb"
            ldLibs.addAll(["log"])
            CFlags.add("-Wall")
            CFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni/android").absolutePath)
            CFlags.add("-O3")
        }

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "src/main/jni/libusb"
                    }
                    dependencies {
                        project ":dependency_module"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the project level build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin was part of an [experimental and old version](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) of the current build system.

You should rewrite your gradle file to work with [the current build system](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle). Either let Android Studio generate the necessary additions by [linking to your CMake file](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds), or copy from a known-good sample like the [HelloJNI](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle) sample:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    ndkVersion '21.2.6472646'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.hellojni'
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'cpuArch'
    productFlavors {
        arm8 {
            dimension 'cpuArch'
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
        x86_64 {
            dimension 'cpuArch'
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'x86_64', 'x86'
            }
        }
        universal {
            dimension 'cpuArch'
            // include all default ABIs. with NDK-r16,  it is:
            //   armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```